# I need my bot to ignore messages by users with a specific role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My bot needs to ignore posts by people with a specific role.

I have written this code and it should be working but every command under this piece of code doesn't work.

I receive no error message(s) and my bot is fine above this piece of code.
What do I need to change?

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "ROLE NAME")) {return;}
})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) has a [`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) named `ROLE NAME`, not the actual [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

[`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) has a property called [`roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles), which contains all the roles of [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "ROLE NAME")) return false;

    // Execute your commands here.
});
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but when i changed my code to that i started to get the error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null

Comment: The command must be executed in a server, not in DMs.

Comment: the bot is executed within a server and I am unsure of what is causing the issue
i am running the bot on v12.3.1 if that helps

Comment: Could you provide your entire code? I'm not sure what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking if the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) has the [`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role), not the [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild).

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name == "ROLE NAME")) return;

    // code...
});
```

You can use the [`.some()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=some) method, which will check if any item in the [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) ([the member's roles](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles)) passes a test you give. In this case, the test is if the role name equals `ROLE NAME`